# Why is Entity Framework calling my stored procedure but returning an incorrect value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure that simply returns the total number of records divided by whatever value is passed in. This is to aid in pagination on a website.

However, I am using the entity framework to bind to that stored procedure and it's returning `-1` for all calls to it. When I interrogate the stored procedure using SQL Management Studio, it comes back with the correct value.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAuditRecordPageCount]
@Count INTEGER
AS
RETURN ((SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM AuditRecords) / @Count) + 1
```

And my call to the entity framework in C# is this:

```
int pageCount;
using (Entities entities = new Entities())
{
    pageCount = entities.GetAuditRecordPageCount(count);
}
```

Am I correct in writing the C# code this way?

As per a request in the comments, the SQL generated by EF is:

```
exec [dbo].[GetAuditRecordPageCount] @Count=100
```

Comment: What's in your GetAuditRecordPageCount method?

Comment: Can you use SQL Profiler to see what SQL was generated by EF?

Comment: @IronMan84 That's just the automatically generated code by EF.

Comment: @DaveShaw It's in the question text now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried that?
http://www.devtoolshed.com/using-stored-procedures-entity-framework-scalar-return-values

I think your procedure will look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAuditRecordPageCount]
@Count INTEGER
AS
declare @retVal int
set @retVal = ((SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM AuditRecords) / @Count) + 1
select @retVal
```

And in the c# code:

```
int? pageCount;
using (Entities entities = new Entities())
{
   pageCount = entities.GetAuditRecordPageCount(count).SingleOrDefault();

   if (pageCount.HasValue)
   {
      //do something here
   }
   else
   {

   }
}
```

Don't forget to put "Scalars: Int32" in edit function Import screen.

Comment: I did something quite similar to this. It works well and is the "proper way". Thank you.