# How to fetch return value from stored procedure in entity framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure which inserts new records from service to the database or update existing record. 
But I need to display true if it is inserted/updated successfully and if it fails, I need to display false in response.

so in my stored procedure call from EF

```
result = database.usp_sp_name(parameters);
if (result==0)
    return true;
else 
    return false;
```

I tried the above code since I read in MSDN site that if successful transaction means, result will be 0. But even its inserting record or updating record, I am getting response as false.

Comment: That should work. If you call that SP from Management Studio, it returns 0? You can debug the code for the SP in Entity Framework, there you can see how it's called and what it returns. If it's not working, you should at least be able to find what's the exact point that is failing.

Comment: Does the stored proc return a value at the end of the proc?

Comment: Nope. I meant return_Value parameter which is default in stored procedure

Comment: Did you tried that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130661/why-is-entity-framework-calling-my-stored-procedure-but-returning-an-incorrect-v http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735477/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440896/stored-procedure-always-returning-0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253522/stored-procedure-returns-incorrect-scalar-value-of-1-instead-of-return-value#autocomment64725743

Comment: You should include the code that executes the sproc. It's not clear how this relates to Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, create a bool that will hold the result of your storedproc and will return true if the result of your storedproc is 1. Otherwise false.

```
bool result = _entites.StoredProc(parameters);
return (result == 1) ? true: false;
```

But in your stored proc
You should create a procedure that will return a value like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProc]
    @parameter
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result int
    DECLARE @param nvarchar(255)
    SET @param = @parameter

    INSERT INTO (field1) VALUES (@param)

    IF @@ERROR = 0
        SET @result = 1
    ELSE 
        SET @result = 0

RETURN @result
```

@@Error returns 0 if the T-SQl statement encountered no errors. You can use that to set the result to 1 or 0. Refer to this link for more info for [@@error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790(v=sql.90).aspx).